# Graphing in Real Analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, graphing-functions

I am having trouble with the following question.

If we fix $a\in[-1,1]$ and define $h_a(x)=\frac{1}{2}(|x-a|+(x-a)))$

I am trying to sketch the graph of $h_{\frac{1}{2}}$ on $[-1,1]$

What does the $\frac{1}{2}$ refer to in $h_\frac{1}{2}$. Do I need to plug that in for $a$ in the equation $h_a(x)=\frac{1}{2}(|x-a|+(x-a)))$?

I have provided a link to a wolfram graph however I am not sure if this is correct or not,

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2(%7Cx-a%7C%2B(x-a))+where+a%3D1%2F2

Comment: Yes you plug in $a$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ and then consider the cases in order to sketch the graph

Comment: @mrnovice, what do you mean by cases?

Comment: Whenever a function has a modulus sign in it, you must consider separately the cases when the contents of the modulus is negative, and when it is positive. e.g. $y=|x|$ can be defined as $y=x , x\geq 0$ and $y=-x , x<0$

Comment: Okay I'll type this as an answer.

Comment: @mrnovice thanks very much for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a function has a modulus sign in it, you must consider separately the cases when the contents of the modulus is negative, and when it is positive. e.g. $y=|x|$ can be defined as $y=x , x\geq 0$ and $y=-x , x<0$

We have $f_{a}(x) =  \frac{1}{2}[ |x-a|+(x-a)]$

Then $f_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \frac{1}{2}[ |x-\frac{1}{2}|+(x-\frac{1}{2})]$

We have two cases to consider:

Case $(1)$:  $$x-\frac{1}{2} \geq 0 \implies x\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Case $(2)$: $$x<\frac{1}{2}$$

Note that in general:

$|x| = x$ for $x \geq 0$ and $|x| = -x$ for $x<0$

So firstly consider case $(1)$:

$|x-\frac{1}{2}| = x-\frac{1}{2} \implies f_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \frac{1}{2}[ x-\frac{1}{2}+x-\frac{1}{2}] =x-\frac{1}{2}$

Then consider case $(2)$:

$|x-\frac{1}{2}| = \frac{1}{2} - x \implies f_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \frac{1}{2}[ -x+\frac{1}{2}+x-\frac{1}{2}] = 0$

So for $x\geq \frac{1}{2}, f_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}$

and for $x<\frac{1}{2}, f_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)=0$ which should be simple to sketch

Comment: thanks for your submission, would setting $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and then plugging in different values for $x$ between $[-1,1]$ work also?

Comment: It could help you to understand the shape of the graph, but it wouldn't give you the general equation of it. In this case you might get away with it, but for more complex ones you'd run into a stone wall.

Comment: also, the equation is $h_a(x)=\frac{1}{2}(|x-a|+(x-a)))$, not $f_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \frac{1}{2}[ |x-\frac{1}{2}|+(x-\frac{1}{2})]$

Comment: only one part of the equation has absolute values, not the whole thing

Comment: @user104 Yes I know, the square brackets are not a modulus sign, it's just to make reading easier

Comment: oh yes my mistake I got a little confused there, does the graph from wolfram alpha supplied in the question look correct?

Comment: Yes, its correct, as you can see on their graph when $x<\frac{1}{2}, f(x) = 0$ and when $x\geq \frac{1}{2}, f(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: okay so when x>=1/2 the graph changes from a line at 0 to a linear graph

Comment: thanks so much for your submission

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the $1/2$ in the equation means that you plug it in for $a$ in the equation. The wolfram graph looks correct.

Comment: so then what should the x and y axis be? should they remain the same and be x,y and how do I factor $[-1,1]$ into the equation? is that the value for the x axis I need to include?

Comment: For each fixed $a$, you have a new function of $x$, which you call $h_a (x)$. Since this is a function of $x$, the x-axis should be for the variable $x$, and the y-axis should be for the output $h_a (x)$. The fact that you are sketching on $[-1,1]$ simply means you only plot this function for $x$ between $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: okay so I need to let a=1/2 for the whole thing then plug values of x of [-1,1] to get my values for the y axis $h_a(x)$?

Comment: That is right. Fix $a$, then plug values in for $x$.